# How to Respond to a MenuItem Click

Tags: android, android-menu

I have a code where I have to start another `Intent`, to open the menu I have the following code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem arg0) {
        switch(arg0.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Toast.makeText(this, "There are no Settings!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //added so the code is shorter
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But when I run this code, nothing happens. And when I try to register using the `MenuItem. setOnMenuItemClick(OnMenuItemClickListener)`, the application stops.

Comment: "the application stops" means that you probably have an error in your LogCat that will tell you exactly what went wrong.

Comment: you have to override onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) to handle the menu button click

Answer (score 0):

I first tried to override `onMenuItemClick(MenuItem)`, which was wrong, the answer is what I got by a comment posted here.
So here is the answer:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Toast.makeText(this, "There are no Settings!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //added so the code is shorter
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)` method has to be overrided (no implements needed in the class definition).